# How "disadvantage" works on Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How precisely does the StarCraft 2 handicap feature work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5841/how-precisely-does-the-starcraft-2-handicap-feature-work)

When I play "Create AI Game" or another multiplayer mode, appears the options:
"difficulty", "race", "color", "disadvantage", where "disadvantage" is a percentual value, like "100%", "90%", "80%",...

How this "disadvantage" works? It's a just starting disadvantage or some another thing?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5841/how-precisely-does-the-starcraft-2-handicap-feature-work